# how to find out jsp coding(background code) to page(view part)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, jsp-tags

My project is mvc java web application with 1000s of jsp pages.

I want to check autocomplete is properly working in all jsp pages, wherever we are using the code `event.keycode==13`.

I found the following code in javascript (using ctrl+shift+f in netbeans).

```
(event.keycode==13)
```

I got many js and jsp page results. I am very confused to find out exact page while running the project.

How can I detect the actual jsp page when running?

Comment: Likely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582428/about-jsp-source-code

Comment: no it is not an duplicate that question is different.