# Spring and Tiles - manually rendering JSP files

Tags: spring, jsp, tiles

We are using Spring 3 and Apache Tiles to create web application that runs on Tomcat 7.

Is it possible, using those tools to manually generate HTML from JSP files in java code during runtime?

For example, I have `sample.jsp` with some dynamically generated content based on a contents of a passed model. I would like to store rendered HTML from JSP in String object.

On a very high level of abstraction:

```
String renderedHtml=renderHtmlFromJSP(jspName,model);
```

If not, is it possible to dynamically change definition of Tiles elements? For example

```
<put-attribute name="headerRight" value="dynamically_set_value" />
```

?

Answer (score 1):

This question can be coupled with this one: [Execute and render JSP inside a Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983361/execute-and-render-jsp-inside-a-filter)
So your `renderHtmlFromJSP` can look like:

```
String renderHtmlFromJSP(
      String fileName, 
      ???? dataModel, 
      HttpServletRequest sourceRequest){
   //you need emulate response to produce output in string (see bellow)
   MyStringResponse resp = new MyStringResponse();
   sourceRequest
        .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/header.jsp")
        .include(request, resp);
   resp.flushBuffer();
   return resp.getMyInternalBufferContent(); 
}
```

To implement MyStringResponse use [HttpServletResponseWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) override method [getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponseWrapper.html#getOutputStream%28%29) and return there instance of ByteArrayOutputStream