# Execute JSP with Jetty 7.3 without javac

Tags: java, jsp, jetty

The problem:
I have a web application which is served by Jetty webserver v 7.3. I have a JSP page in the application. When I run the Jetty on system which has JDK(has javac) installed everything works fine. I want to port this to a system which has JRE(does not have javac). When I run the Jetty I get an error.

The solution:
Pre-compile the JSP into Servlet. Generate application war file which includes this servlet. Let jetty execute the Servlet in place of compiling and executing JSP at runtime.

I tried to pre-compile JSP using JSPC ant target. But it is generating an empty .java file. My target code is as follows.

```
<jspc srcdir="${web.dir}"
          destdir="${build.classes.dir}"
          package="x.y.z"
          verbose="9"
          classpathref="project.class.path">
      <include name="**/index.jsp"/>
    </jspc>
```

Kindly suggest me a proper approach. If my approach is correct, kindly point out the mistake that I am making in configuring the ant task.

Comment: If you cannot make this work, then consider adding ecj to your Jetty installation as described in http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JSP

Comment: Just a thought, have you tried running ant with the -debug flag?  It might report something a bit more useful than simply giving your the empty file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the ant supplied `jspc` task.  It is deprecated, flaky, and only worked with Tomcat 4 installed (certain versions).

Instead, install Tomcat (whichever version best supports the same JSP/Servlet specs as your deployed Jetty) and call the Jasper compiler via the Tomcat provided Ant task.  [An example for Tomcat 5 is available here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jasper-howto.html).

Note that once the JSP pages are compiled to Servlets, the Servlets are compiled to classes, etc.  You don't need any of this "build environment" in your Jetty deployment environment.

[Also note that the commentary near the end of the ant supplied `jspc` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jspc.html).  I don't know if it is still relevant, but it is interesting.