# Can JStestDriver be used to test js code within JSP files?

Tags: javascript, jsp, unit-testing, js-test-driver, data-integration

Quick question:

It is possible to do unit testing, particularly with JStestDriver, on Javascript code written inside JSP files?

Or I have to necessarily extract it into external js files?

Comment: Did you try it out? What happened?

Comment: actually, I didn't, because I do not have any clue about it.
I mean you cannot load the JSP file in the load section of the JSTD cofiguration file...

Comment: Maybe it is possible using the workaround of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636735/event-listeners-js-test-driver/14642901#14642901

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript source with the substitutions from the compiled JSP have to be extracted into separate files. Here is an example using CoffeeScript:

- [CoffeeScript TDD](http://css.dzone.com/articles/coffeescript-tdd-example)

For JSP in particular, it is necessary to [find the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431077/) to the compiled output and [debug](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRTLW_9.0.1/com.ibm.etools.pagedesigner.doc/topics/tdbgjsp.html) the result. Use `jspc`, the JSP compiler, to test the output with JsTestDriver.

> The jspc command-line tool enables you to precompile JSPs at the command line.
>
> You must disable dynamic reloading of JSP when deploying a web application archive that has precompiled JSP without the corresponding jsp source files.

**References**

- [Compiling JSPs Using the Command-Line Compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-0790/abxcc/)
- [Debugging JSP Files](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/tdbgjsp.htm)
- [Jasper How-To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html)
- [jspc Ant Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jspc.html)
- [Tomcat JSP/JSTL without HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528697/1113772)